# problemas con swall alert y funcion c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

estoy implementado Swall alert en mi sistema en el apartado que tiene de confirmación decidí añadir una llamada al servidor específicamente a la función eliminar el problema es que al depurar el programa hace la función eliminar.. sin necesidad de presionar el botón confirmar que tiene el swall Alert.. tal vez lo estoy haciendo mal porfavor me ayudan a guiarme

mi codigo JavaScript es el siguiente

```
<script>
        function msj_producto()
            {
                swal({
                    title: "Esta seguro que desea eliminar esta publicacion",
                    text: "",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "rgb(140, 212, 245)",
                    confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                    },
                function (isConfirm)
                {
                    if (isConfirm)
                    {
                        <% eliminar(); %>
                    }
                    else { }
                });
            }
<script>
```

Y la funcion la tengo en el servidor esta de la siguiente manera

```
public void eliminar()
{
    //Este es un alert de prueba
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "elimina", "alert('prueba');", true);
}
```

Estoy utilizando asp.net

Answer (score 0):

creo que no tienes bien construido el *sweetalert*, falta la sintaxis de promesas (*promises*), prueba con esto:

```
<script>
        function msj_producto()
            {
                swal({
                    title: "Esta seguro que desea eliminar esta publicacion",
                    text: "",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "rgb(140, 212, 245)",
                    confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
                    closeOnConfirm: true,
                })
                .then ((isConfirm)=>{
                    if (isConfirm)
                    {
                        <% eliminar(); %>
                    }
                    else { }
                });
            }
<script>
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder.. probe el codigo que me sugirio pero no funciona aun asi sigue entrando a la `funcion eliminar () ` que tengo del lado del sevidor...

Comment: Prueba quitando el 'closeOnConfirm', a ver si así lo hace correctamente

Comment: acabo de probarlo, pero sigue sin funcionar